# How inject data from ('another') model in admin?

Tags: django

I have **User model**:

```
class PublisherProfile(models.Model):
    publisher_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user_profile = models.OneToOneField(Profile, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, verbose_name=_("user profile"))
```

**In admin** I registered this model:

```
@admin.register(PublisherProfile)
class PublisherProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        "publisher_id",
        "user_profile",
    )
```

**In another model** I have:

```
class PublisherOffer(models.Model):
    offer_owner = models.ForeignKey('user.PublisherProfile', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_("offer owner"), )
    title = models.CharField(_('Offer title'), help_text=_('Title of the offer.'), max_length=250, blank=False,
                             null=False)
```

**How can I inject all PublisherOffer to PublisherProfileAdmin?**

Answer (score 0):

You can inject all PublisherOffer to PublisherProfileAdmin by adding one more field in the PublisherProfileAdmin in this way:

```
@admin.register(PublisherProfile)
class PublisherProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        "publisher_id",
        "user_profile",
        "offers_title"
    )
    def offers_title(self,obj):
        return list(PublisherOffer.objects.filter(offer_owner=obj).values_list('title',flat=True))

@admin.register(PublisherOffer)
class PublisherOfferAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields=("offer_owner","title")
```

Output looks like this:
[image]

---

To get the PublisherOffer inside PublisherProfile preview:

In admin.py file:

```
@admin.register(PublisherProfile)
class PublisherProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        "publisher_id",
        "user_profile",
        "offers_title"
    )
    readonly_fields=('offers_title',)
```

In model.py file:

```
class PublisherProfile(models.Model):
    publisher_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user_profile = models.OneToOneField(Volunteer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, verbose_name="user profile")
    
    @property
    def offers_title(self):
        return list(PublisherOffer.objects.filter(offer_owner=self.publisher_id).values_list('title',flat=True))
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! If it's possible incject this like InLines? 
I want to have a preview inside AdminModel

Comment: https://ifotos.pl/zobacz/11jpg_qqaxswa.jpg  <- when you go to the preview of a given profile to have its offers inside. 
Just like InLines works

Comment: Thank you but still it is a list. I need each offer as record.
Is it possible for them to be on the same basis as InLine. 
Each offer - one clickable record (In the same way as InLines)

Comment: You can play around and get the desired result.